# ReactJS | OnSubmit is not a function with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux, formik

I have a simple form Form with React. I am using `formik` to handle form validation, on the frontEnd. Here is my component:

```
class GroupDetailsForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = values => {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props;
    onSubmit(values);
  };

  render() {
    const { group } = this.props;

    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ ...group }}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        render={({ values, touched, errors, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="groupName">
                    Group name <span className="text-danger">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    value={values.name}
                    name="name"
                    className={classNames('form-control', {
                      'is-invalid': errors.name && touched.name
                    })}
                    id="groupName"
                    placeholder="PaymentsTeam"
                  />
                  {!!errors.name && touched.name && (
                    <div className="text-danger">{errors.name}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="groupDescription">Description</label>
                  <textarea
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    value={values.description}
                    name="description"
                    className={classNames('form-control', {
                      'is-invalid': errors.description && touched.description
                    })}
                    id="groupDescription"
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder=""
                  />
                  {!!errors.description && touched.description && (
                    <div className="text-danger">{errors.description}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

When I click Submit, I get this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: onSubmit is not a function at Object.GroupDetailsForm.values [as onSubmit] (index.jsx:18)`

Not sure what the problem is here. Can someone help? The code seems fine to me. I tried to play with it, accessing the OnSubmit on different parts of the Component and not on the form itself, but with no luck.

The mistake is probably something trivial but I cannot see it. Can someone help???

Down you can see the Component I implement `GroupDetailsForm`. It is the whole component, to make it easier.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import GroupDetailsForm from '../../components/GroupDetailsForm';
import { Actions } from '../../actions';

// Importing Styles
import './styles.scss';

export class GroupsCreateScreen extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    listGroups: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    securityMode: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { listGroups } = this.props;
    listGroups();
  }

  render() {
    const group = {
      name: '',
      description: ''
    };

    return (
      <div className="container mt-5 bg-white p-5">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            <h4>Step 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <GroupDetailsForm group={group} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            <h4>Step 2</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            <h4>Step 3</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            <h4>Step 4</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state // todo to be refined
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  ...Actions
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(GroupsCreateScreen);
```

Comment: I just tried removing the `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` from the starting `Form` tag, and now I don't get the error obvisously. I have to put it there, apparently, cause anywhere else, It doesn't even acccess the `onSubmit`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you implement `GroupDetailsForm` with all it's props?

Comment: I just updated the description. PLease check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing `onSubmit` as a prop to `GroupDetailsForm`, but you're trying to access it from `this.props` in your `handleSubmit` function.

You can try this out and it shouldn't complain about `not a function` anymore, obviously you'll need to pass in your real function though.

```
<GroupDetailsForm group={group} onSubmit={values => console.log(values)} />
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. Could you explain it a little bit? I don't think I got it. What do you mean by my real function??

Comment: `GroupDetailsForm` expects you to pass an `onSubmit` function from whatever component is calling it, so somewhere inside `GroupsCreateScreen`, you need to create that function and pass it. If you want `GroupDetailsForm` to just use an internal function, then just do everything inside `handleSubmit` and don't require a function to be passed through `this.props`

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for the explanation.